# tail -F log.log | grep ResponseTime | cut -d = -f 2

Tags: bash, unix, pipe

I have a live log file called log.log and want to catch some matching patterns and values in it:

Example:
log.log is growing and we are searching for lines that have pattern "ResponseTime = VALUE" and we want to extract the matched VALUE:

I am executing:

```
tail -F log.log | grep ResponseTime | cut -d = -f 2 | tr -d " "
```

And I am expecting to see

```
VALUE1
VALUE2
.. etc
```

But it is not working ... what should I do?

Thank you,
NaMo

===========

Thank you, it works now. I am using: 
inotail -f log.log | stdbuf -oL grep ResponseTime | stdbuf -oL cut -d '=' -f 2 | stdbuf -oL tr -d " "

Comment: What happens if you run `cat log.log | grep ResponseTime | cut -d = -f 2 | tr -d " "`? I suspect some data is being cached in the pipeline and it won't get flushed until more data is written to the `log.log` file (or EOF).

Answer (score 10):

[BASH FAQ entry #9: "What is buffering? Or, why does my command line produce no output: tail -f logfile | grep 'foo bar' | awk ..."](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009)

Comment: Thank you, it works. I am using:
inotail -f log.log | stdbuf -oL grep ResponseTime | stdbuf -oL cut -d '=' -f 2 | stdbuf -oL  tr -d " "

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `grep` to `stdbuf -oL grep`.

See [BASHFAQ/009](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it isn't working is that some commands don't flush STDOUT with each output.  Therefore the later commands are never being passed anything.

I would use just one command after `tail` such as:

```
tail -F t.log  | sed '/ResponseTime/!d;s/ResponseTime\s+=\s+(\d+)/\\1/'
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to remove newlines from your output then you can any of the following:

```
| cut -d = -f 2|sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n//;ta' 

| cut -d = -f 2|tr -d '\n'

| cut -d = -f 2|awk '{printf "%s",$0}'
```